# How can I see what commands flyway is sending to my database?

Tags: flyway

I am experimenting with using flyway repair, but I'm curious as to exactly what commands flyway is sending to the target database. Is there a way to configure it to echo the commands?

Answer (score 0):

The `-X` command line option gives a lot more verbose information but doesn't echo out the exact SQL used to repair the history table. All the information is there, though as the log contains entries like

`Repairing Schema History table for version 1.0.1 (Description: create table foo, Type: SQL, Checksum: 1456329846)  ...`

which translates into `UPDATE flyway_schema_history SET description=@p0, type=@p1, checksum=@p2 where version=@p3` in the obvious way

(at least with SQL Server on which I've just run the profiler).

You could submit it as a feature request? https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues